# Flutter: Loading local json file returns null

Tags: flutter

Sorry for my very beginner question, I am trying to teach my self Flutter so i am doing some tutorials from youtube and somehow i get `Invalid argument(s)` error even though i have typed exactly as it is in the tutorial, I tried to debug by printing and first it prints null and then it prints the list with json objects, but when i print `mydata[0]` it prints `The method '[]' was called on null.`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Home(),
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
    ),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeState createState() => new HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Some App"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/data.json'),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              var mydata = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
              print(mydata);
              return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("Name " + mydata[index]['Name']),
                        Text("Age " + mydata[index]['Age']),
                        Text("Gender " + mydata[index]['Gender']),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: mydata == null ? 0 : mydata.length,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you shoe me your data format, so that I can provide a better answer

Comment: Can you add the output of `print(mydata);` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, don't forget the `pubspec.yaml`:

```
  assets:
   - assets/data.json
```

This is the `json`:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "John Doe",
    "Age": "30",
    "Gender": "Male"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jane Doe",
    "Age": "25",
    "Gender": "Female"
  }
]
```

You need to check if Future delivered or not inside builder method of FutureBuilder. Like:

This is the build method:

```dart
class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Some App"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future:
                DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/data.json'),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if(!snapshot.hasData) { /// CRITICAL POINT
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              var myData = json.decode(snapshot.data);
              print(myData);
              return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("Name " + myData[index]['Name']),
                        Text("Age " + myData[index]['Age']),
                        Text("Gender " + myData[index]['Gender']),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: myData == null ? 0 : myData.length,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It's working, but I have better solution for your situation, check it:

[Load and read data from Json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56141871/load-and-read-data-from-json-file/56153595#56153595)

Comment: @SachihiroTakamori I added my other solution, it's a full application code, try it. Don't forget to add file into pubspec.yaml. Also I remember you from Tensor's 2048 video livestream :)